# Error CS0201- can't understand what's wrong with my code

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I want the user to enter his name and get greeted by the console. Can't figure  what I'm doing wrong here...

EDIT : ok looks like `Console.Read` is the problem. Dont know why tho.

```
using System;

namespace Program1
{
    // use can use regions to wrap code in them and they can be collapsed
    #region 
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter ur name : "); // showing a msg to user
            string name = Console.ReadLine(); // defining a string variable and getting input from user
            Console.WriteLine("Hello " + name); // saying hi to user by adding his name that we asked earlier
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to terminate ...");
            Console.Read;
        }
        #endregion // use can use regions to wrap code in them and they can be collapsed
    }
}
```

Comment: Also the #endregion should be after class definition end for better structure else it would look weird when you collapse it.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a parenthesis after Console.Read, should be as following `Console.Read()`

Comment: Thanks! can you help me understand this type of error better? what is the case when this error usually occurs?

Comment: This is a compiler error, you can't compile your code without a proper syntax. Console.ReadLine() is a method and this is the way of calling methods in C#, you always use parenthesis after the method name. Visual studio should give you a error message by underlining the code with red and under Error List window when you try to compile.

Comment: Simple "Console.Read" would call the getter of property "Read" which is not defined on Console. But the error there is, that you cannot call getter without use of the return value anyway.